# Are there any accounts of Charles Peirce's character,cognition and physical appearance?

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details

I am interested in any historical account of the following attributes of Peirce:character,cognition and appearance.

Comment: What's "cognition and appearance"? There is a number of [book-length biographies](https://www.google.com/search?q=c.s.+peirce+biography&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjex6DUuuDsAhUOA6wKHQfvD6gQ_AUoAXoECAYQCQ&biw=1252&bih=548) that probably have whatever that is.

Comment: There is the [Cambridge Companion to Peirce](https://books.google.it/books?id=3suPBY5qh-cC&printsec=frontcover) with portrait (cover) and first chapter dedicated to a bio.